# xpath returns a empty nodelist when grabbing text

Tags: php, xpath

im building a small scraping tool that will scape the urls from a google page. im trying to get the value value from "cite" which holds the url as text. im loading the webpage using curl to the doms load html. when i do a print_r the the results are displayed. so there is no problem with curl

below is my code

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($result);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

            $elements = $xpath->query("//cite[@class='vurls']");

            print_r($elements);

    foreach ($elements as $entry)
    {
     print_r($entry);
             //show cite url
    }
```

when i use `//cite[@class='vurls']` in the firefox xpath checker it evaluates and shows all the cite text. but in my code the `$elements` is always empty.

i also tried the full path inside my query

```
//div[@id='ires']/ol[@id='rso']//li/div/div/div/div/cite
```

but it still returns a empty value.

an example query is

> http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=xpath

can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Google is serving different HTML depending on the browser used. Have a look at the HTML you receive in PHP, not in Firefox. There is no `@class` attribute in the `<cite/>` elements, you need to find another way to query them, eg.

```
//div[@class='kv']/cite
```

Anyway: Don't parse Google search results, they offer an API for doing that. Parsing websites is likely to break (because they will change over time, and they do often), APIs are stable.